Link to a route with expo-router outside of the current tab stack while keeping the tab bar visible
I have an expo project using the tabs template (npx create-expo-app --template tabs) targeting native as well as web.
For this example let's say I have three pages:

Explore (List of all items)
Favorites (List of all favorited items)
Details (Details of a single item with the option to favorite it)

The folders look like this:
(tabs)
│   _layout.tsx
│   explore.tsx
│   favorites.tsx
│
details
│   _layout.tsx
│   [id].tsx
│
_layout.tsx

When I'm in the explore or favorites page and click on an item, I want to be able to link to the details page from both. However, this results in the page opening on top of the tab navigation. I want to open it in the context of the tab's stack, keeping the tab navigation visible.
Now I know if I structure my code like this it would work:
(tabs)
│   _layout.tsx
│
└── explore
│   │   _layout.tsx
│   │   index.tsx
│   │   [id].tsx <- Details page
│
└── favorites
│   │   _layout.tsx
│   │   index.tsx
│   │   [id].tsx <- Details page
│
_layout.tsx

But this would result in duplicate routes for the web: /explore/test-item and /favorites/test-item. It would also make it difficult to deep-link to them. I looked into shared routes, but I can't wrap my head around how they would work in this case (In my project, the routes are nested differently, so it would be more like /profile/favorites/ and /explore/ which would both need to open /details/test-item/ in their respective stack. I'm using the <Stack> Component provided by expo-router which doesn't have the component property from react-navigation.

I have found a solution that works (with a small caveat - see below).
The solution
Use shared routes to group all top-level tab routes and nested shared routes together, then use _layout.tsx's segment prop to specify the top-level route for the currently active tab.
Implementation
Consider an app with three tabs - Home, Search and Library - and a nested Item screen which needs to be shown within every tab stack.
First setup the following file structure:
app/
├── _layout.tsx // defines root stack with single (tabs) screen
└── (tabs)/
    ├── _layout.tsx
    └── (home,search,library)/
        ├── _layout.tsx
        ├── index.tsx
        ├── search.tsx
        ├── library.tsx
        └── item.tsx // This is a nested shared route and not a tab

Within your (tabs) _layout.tsx file, make sure each tab points to the relevant group:
<Tabs screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} >
  <Tabs.Screen name="(home)" options={{ title: 'Home' }} />
  <Tabs.Screen name="(search)" options={{ title: 'Search' }} />
  <Tabs.Screen name="(library)" options={{ title: 'Your Library' }} />
</Tabs>

Then, within your (home,search,library) shared routes _layout.tsx file, use the segment prop to switch on each segment and define each root stack screen for each tab:
const Layout = ({ segment }) => {
    const rootScreen = useMemo(() => {
        switch (segment) {
            case '(home)':
                return <Stack.Screen name="index" options={{ title: 'Home' }} />
            case '(search)':
                return <Stack.Screen name="search" options={{ title: 'Search' }} />
            case '(library)':
                return <Stack.Screen name="library" options={{ title: 'Your Library' }} />
        }
    }, [segment])

    return (
        <Stack>
            {rootScreen}
            <Stack.Screen name="item" options={{ title: 'Item' }} />
        </Stack>
    )
}

export default Layout

Explanation
The shared routes  feature is essentially 'short hand' for defining each of the three groups. The file structure defined above uses this 'short hand', and is identical to:
app/
├── _layout.tsx // defines root stack with single (tabs) screen
└── (tabs)/
    ├── _layout.tsx
    ├── (home)/
    │   ├── _layout.tsx
    │   ├── index.tsx
    │   └── item.tsx
    ├── (search)/
    │   ├── _layout.tsx
    │   ├── search.tsx
    │   └── item.tsx
    └── (library)/
        ├── _layout.tsx
        ├── library.tsx
        └── item.tsx

Implications

Navigating to /item will push the Item screen onto the current stack ✅
Navigating to (search)/item will push the Item screen on the search stack and switch to the Search tab ✅

Caveat
Because all tabs are defined within the (home,search,library) directory, all nested screens within this directory will be accessible from all tabs. This may not be a problem in practice, but worth noting.
